# Array[0] is changing while entering the "for" loop, can't figure out why

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, variable-length-array

I'm doing a challenge on HackerRank got the method figured out but there's a slight error I cannot figure out. Further information if needed is https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays

Basically I only have a problem with arr[0]. It's storing arr[0] as 'aba', then once it hits the first for loop it changes to 'ab'. Why?

Input:

```
4
aba
baba
aba
xzxb
3
aba
xzxb
ab
```

Code:

```
int main() {
  int i, j;
  int n;
  int q;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  char* arr[n];
  char* test[q];
  char* s;
  int counter[q];

  for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    counter[i] = 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(20);
    scanf("%s", arr[i]);
  }

  scanf("%d", &q);

  for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    test[i] = malloc(20);
    scanf("%s", test[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < q; j++) {

      if (strcmp(arr[i], test[j]) == 0) {

        counter[j]++;
      } else {
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", counter[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: char*test[q] declared before q was given!

Comment: why do you declare all your variables at the top of the function? This was necessary in C89, but it's been ... almost 30 years. It's been considered bad practice for a longggg time.

Comment: Will keep this in mind, thanks! And as to answer, I'm ~3 week year old coder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `test` and `counter` as array of size `q` before having initialize `q`. Move there declaration just after `scanf("%d",&q);`. Also move the initializing loop of `counter` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int i, j;
  int n;
  int q;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  char* arr[n];
  char* s;

  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    arr[i]= malloc(20);
    scanf("%s",arr[i]);
  }

  scanf("%d", &q);
  int counter[q];
  char* test[q]; 

  for(i=0; i<q; i++) {
    counter[i] = 0;
  }
  for(i=0; i<q; i++) {
    test[i]= malloc(20);
    scanf("%s",test[i]);
  }

  for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<q; j++) {
      if (strcmp(arr[i],test[j]) == 0) {
        counter[j]++;
      }
    }
  }
  for(i=0; i<q; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", counter[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you!!! Argh, can't believe the silly things I do sometimes. Will accept this answer when the minimum acceptance time is over.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  int i, j;
  int n;
  int q;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  char* arr[n];


  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr[i] = malloc(20);
    scanf("%s", arr[i]);
  }

  scanf("%d", &q);

  char* test[q];
  char* s;
  int counter[q];


  for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    counter[i] = 0;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    test[i] = malloc(20);
    scanf("%s", test[i]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < q; j++) {

      if (strcmp(arr[i], test[j]) == 0) {

        counter[j]++;
      } else {
      }
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", counter[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

try this, use varialble after declaration and initialization